# PDE solution does not satisfy Neumann boundary conditions using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the free particle Schrodinger equation in 1D (hbar =1, Energy = 1, mass = 1), But specifying conditions only on x==0:

```
k = Sqrt[2];
op = Inactivate[Div[{{-0.5}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] - u[x];
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == NeumannValue[0, x == 0], 
DirichletCondition[u[x] == Cos[k x], x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[{sol[x] , Cos[k x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The blue line is the numeric solution, and it is obviously not the expected solution (in orange), since the derivative in x==0 is not zero. 
I understand that specifying the Neumann value is not needed since its default is zero, but it isn't zero here!

What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Both `NeumannValue` and `DirichletCondition` are set to apply at `x==0`. In such cases the `DirichletCondition` will trump the `NeumannValue`. Besides the `NeumannValue` is set to zero which means that the natural boundary condition is 0, the boundary integral vanishes. I think you want the `DirichletCondition` at `x==1`:

```
k = Sqrt[2];
op = Inactivate[Div[{{-0.5}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] - u[x];
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == NeumannValue[0, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == Cos[k x], x == 1]}, u, {x, 0, 1}];
```

But `NeumannValue[0,...]` is equivalent to not specifying anything at all:

```
k = Sqrt[2];
op = Inactivate[Div[{{-0.5}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] - u[x];
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == Cos[k x], x == 1]}, u, {x, 0, 1}];

Plot[{sol[x] - Cos[k x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am actually interested in solving using conditions only at x == 0. I want to use `DiriclehtCondition` and `NeumannValue` to get the equivalent solution to this: `NDSolveValue[{-1/2 u''[x] - u[x] == 0, u[0] == Cos[k 0] , 
  u'[0] == -k Sin [k 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1}]` Is it not possible?

Comment: @AmitAbir, no, that's not possible. Why do you have that restriction?

Comment: @AmitAbir, note that the above `NDSolve` does a time integration, while the FEM is a spatial discretization method.

Comment: Well, eventually I wish to solve this problem in 3 dimensions. In my problem there are two concentric spheres and I wish to solve Schrodinger's equation in the region between the spheres. The problem is I have boundary condition only on the inner sphere (Both Dirichlet and Neumann). Is it not solvable? Is it not possible to specify both Neumann and Dirichlet condition on the same part of the boundary? Is there any other method to solve this other then FEM?

Comment: @AmitAbir, if one does not specify boundary conditions on the outer sphere that implies that a Neumann zero boundary condition is used; it's not possible to have both Dirichlet and Neumann conditions at the same position. Is it generally not solvable, that I do not know.

Comment: Can you try to explain what's the problem with having both conditions (Neumann and Dirichlet) at the same position? Is it mathematical constraint or the specific implementation of NDSolve?

Comment: The point is not so much that you can not specify two conditions at one side. Even if you could do that, then on the right hand side you still implicitly have a Neumann zero value defined - which the solver will and does satisfy as you can see in the example in your question. There is no way to remove that boundary integral the makes the Neumann condition. It's part of the (general not NDSolve) FEM framework. Perhaps the problem can be reformulated or though of in a different way to use FEM to solve it, but I do not know how. Perhaps you could split the eqn into two coupled equations. Not sure

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @AmitAbir, if you do come up with a solution, let me know. I'd be interested to learn how you did this. One other idea might be to make this a time dependent problem and have the Dirichlet and Neumann conditions be the intial conditions for time integration.